# Animate Delaunay triangulation - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, delaunay, matplotlib-animation

Is it possible to animate Delaunay triangulation using Matplotlib? The following plots vertices grouped by `Item` and `Time`. I'm hoping to animate this instead of plotting each iteration.

I may also have time points that don't contain enough points to adequately plot the triangulation. For these time points, I'm just hoping to pass that period and move onto the subsequent time point.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# data frame containing time points without adequate points (3)
#df = pd.DataFrame({
#    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],  
#    'Item' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','B'],                  
#    'X' : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2], 
#    'Y' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6],                         
#        })

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,10))

grid = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gridsize = (1, 2)

ax = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 1))

A_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'A']
B_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'B']

def make_points(x):
    return np.array(list(zip(x['X'], x['Y'])))

A_points = A_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)
B_points = B_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)

for p in A_points:
    tri = Delaunay(p)
    a_del = ax.triplot(*p.T, tri.simplices, color = 'orange')

for p in B_points:
    tri = Delaunay(p)
    b_del = ax.triplot(*p.T, tri.simplices, color = 'purple')

#def animate(i) :

    #a_del.set_data#()
    #b_del.set_data#()    

#ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, blit = False)
```

Edit 2:

I'm hoping to keep the figure, axes stable as I plot other objects on it. As such, I just want to animate the change in the triangulation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],  
    'Item' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','A','B','B'],                  
    'X' : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5], 
    'Y' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4],                         
        })


A_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'A']
B_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'B']

def make_points(x):
    return np.array(list(zip(x['X'], x['Y'])))

A_points = A_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)
B_points = B_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)

A_points = A_points.values
B_points = B_points.values

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,10))

grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
gridsize = (2, 2)

ax = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan = 2)
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 0))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12,8))

def one_frame(i):

    ax[0].clear();ax[1].clear()

    try:
        a_points = np.unique(A_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_a = Delaunay(a_points)
        ax[0].triplot(*a_points.T, tri_a.simplices, color = 'orange')
    except Exception:
        pass

    try:
        b_points = np.unique(B_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_b = Delaunay(b_points)
        ax[1].triplot(*b_points.T, tri_b.simplices, color = 'purple')
    except Exception:
        pass


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,one_frame, blit = False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible mate, try this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# data frame containing time points without adequate points (3)
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],  
   'Item' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','B'],                  
   'X' : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2], 
   'Y' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6],                         
       })
A_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'A']
B_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'B']

def make_points(x):
    return np.array(list(zip(x['X'], x['Y'])))

A_points = A_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)
B_points = B_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)

A_points = A_points.values
B_points = B_points.values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,8))

def one_frame(i):
    
    ax[0].clear();ax[1].clear()
    
    try:
        a_points = np.unique(A_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_a = Delaunay(a_points)
        ax[0].triplot(*a_points.T, tri_a.simplices, color = 'orange')
    except Exception as e:
        print("frame %i, point a can't print because of \n%s" % (i,e))
    
    try:
        b_points = np.unique(B_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_b = Delaunay(b_points)
        ax[1].triplot(*b_points.T, tri_b.simplices, color = 'purple')
    except Exception as e:
        print("frame %i, point b can't print because of \n%s" % (i,e))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,one_frame,range(3), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=1)
```

The output is

[image: output]

---

**UPDATE**

It is possible to keep the `fig` and `ax`, the idea is to remove the triangles (`Line2D` object) of the last frame at the beginning of each frame by

```
for item in triangles_a:
    try:
        item.remove()
    except Exception as e:
        continue 
for item in triangles_b:
    try:
        item.remove()
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

Remove the triangles won't affect other parts of the `fig` and `ax`. **For example, in the example below, the two circles won't be affected during the animation.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# data frame containing time points without adequate points (3)
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],  
   'Item' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','A','B','A','B','A','B','B','A','B'],                  
   'X' : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2], 
   'Y' : [5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6],                         
       })
A_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'A']
B_coord = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'B']

def make_points(x):
    return np.array(list(zip(x['X'], x['Y'])))

A_points = A_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)
B_points = B_coord.groupby(['Time']).apply(make_points)

A_points = A_points.values
B_points = B_points.values

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,10))
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
gridsize = (2, 2)

ax0 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan = 2)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 0), colspan = 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (1, 1), colspan = 1)

ax1.set_xlim(0,8);ax1.set_ylim(0,8)
ax2.set_xlim(0,8);ax2.set_ylim(0,8)
    
# things that won't be affected 
circle_0 = plt.Circle((4,4), 2, color='violet',fill=False)
ax1.add_artist(circle_0)

circle_1 = plt.Circle((5,4), 2, color='deepskyblue',fill=False)
ax2.add_artist(circle_1)
    
triangles_a,triangles_b = [],[]
def one_frame(i):
    
    global triangles_a,triangles_b
    for item in triangles_a:
        try:
            item.remove()
        except Exception as e:
            continue 
    for item in triangles_b:
        try:
            item.remove()
        except Exception as e:
            continue
    
    try:
        a_points = np.unique(A_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_a = Delaunay(a_points)
        obj_a = ax1.triplot(*a_points.T, tri_a.simplices, color = 'orange')
        triangles_a.extend(obj_a)
    except Exception as e:
        print("frame %i, point a can't print because of \n%s" % (i,e))
    
    try:
        b_points = np.unique(B_points[i],axis=0)
        tri_b = Delaunay(b_points)
        obj_b = ax2.triplot(*b_points.T, tri_b.simplices, color = 'purple')
        triangles_b.extend(obj_b)
    except Exception as e:
        print("frame %i, point b can't print because of \n%s" % (i,e))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,one_frame,range(3), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=1)
```

the output

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @meTchaikovsky. You've helped me out a fair bit! Similar to the last one, is it possible to keep the fig, ax fixed and just plot the change in triangulation?

Comment: You're welcome @jonboy, I also earn a good amount of rep! :D. It is also possible, check out my updated post.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am still hoping to keep the figure fixed beforehand. I manipulate the figure and axes a fair bit and just update the changes. My actual grid is more complex. I've adjusted the question to highlight this. I might have to ask a separate question. Sorry for this

Comment: @jonboy You're welcome, I don't understand, in my updated post the `fig` and `ax` are fixed, only the triangles of the last frame will be removed at the beginning of each frame. Remove the triangles won't affect other parts of the `fig` and `ax`.

Comment: I'v used grid spec in my actual code because I manipulate the output for each individual subplot. I have 5-6 subplots and I only want to animate the triangulation in one of these. I'll see if I can change the other subplots with `plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))`, instead of `gridspec`. I've inserted a figure after edit 2 that displays the figure that resembles mine

Comment: @jonboy Using `gridspec` is just the same as using `ax`, check out my updated post, I use `gridspec` there.

Comment: Brilliant. Got it going. Thanks so much for all this